# Enable shadow copy where VHD files are stored?

Tags: windows-server-2012, best-practices

Should I enable Shadow Copy on the volume that stores our Hyper-V VHDs?

This same volume also has all our file shares, which is why I want to turn on shadow copy.

If I do enable it, will it eat up my storage space, what with VHDs being quite big and all?